# Tkinter Window Composition Object causes Attribute Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, attributes

**What I Am Doing:**

I am currently working on a Rock, Paper, Scissors game. I actually only wanted to do this through the console but given how crowded that eventually gets I decided to switch to tkinter. I created custom classes for every component of the GUI (mainly to get to know OOP). I used compositions since I have been advised to steer clear of inheritance when working with Thin Wrappers.

**Expected Results VS Actual Results:**

I created an instance of my Custom Window Class (name: *GameWindow*) and gave it the parameter (*window_name*) which I specified in the *innit* function. Afterwards I created an instance of my custom Button class (name: *ChoiceButton*) and passed the needed parameters specified in the *innit* function. I then used the *.grid* manager to place the button at the specified location.

My expected result is obvious: A window opens with a button placed at the specified location.

The actual result is this: A window opens, with no button in it. If I exit the code through the editor, it does not even through an error. But if I close the window by pressing the **X** button in the top right corner it throws an error which I will append below.

**Troubleshooting so far:**

*1.* Place a frame in the window and then add the button. (*Result:* Does not change anything)

*2.* Create a button from the original tKinter *Button()* class (**NOT** my composed custom class!) and
place it inside the window at the specified location. (*Result:* Does not change anything)

*3.* Step '*1.*' and Step '*2.*' combined. Create a "normal" button and place it in a frame, which has itself been placed at the specified location. (*Result:* Does not change anything)

*3.* Created a "normal" window object from the *tk()* class. Then repeated step *'1.'* to *'3.'*. (*Result:* Window and button appear. The custom button class therefore works. The custom window class does not.)

**The Error And The Code**

Below this you will find the error message seen within the console. As far as the code goes I have only merely included the *GameWindow* Class Code since it seems clear that this is very likely to be the culprit. If you need the full code please do not hesitate to contact me!

**The Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jonas/PycharmProjects/RockPaperScissors/classtestfile.py", line 66, in <module>
    test_frame = Frame(main_Menu, row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3119, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2561, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2530, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'GameWindow' object has no attribute 'tk'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**The Code:**

```
import tkinter


# ||create a class for game windows;
class GameWindow:

    # ||set attributes; window height and width;
    window_height = 525
    window_width = 700

    # ||create __init__ function; self and window_name as parameter;
    def __init__(self, window_name):
        # ||make Tk() master of this class;
        self.master = tkinter.Tk()
        # ||set title of the file to the value of 'window_name';
        self.master.title(window_name)
        # ||create a grid by assigning weight to all rows and columns;
        self.rows = 0  # -- create row counter --;
        while self.rows < 10:  # -- make row counter count up to 9 --;
            self.master.rowconfigure(self.rows, weight=1)  # -- assign weight of 1 to respective row --;
            self.master.columnconfigure(self.rows, weight=1)  # -- assign weight of 1 to respective column --;
            self.rows += 1  # -- increment of 1 the row counter --;
        # save screen width and height in variables;
        width = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
        height = self.master.winfo_screenheight()
        # calculate centered window offset coordinates and save them in respective variables;
        pos_x = (width - self.window_width) // 2
        pos_y = (height - self.window_height) // 2
        # make main window resizable;
        self.master.resizable()
        # initiate geometry manager with aforementioned values;
        self.master.geometry(f"{self.window_width}x{self.window_height}+{pos_x}+{pos_y}")

    # create function to execute the window in within the mainloop;
    def run(self):
        self.master.mainloop()


# create a standard class for choice buttons;
class ChoiceButton:

    # set class attributes
    is_active = False
    # create __init__ function; declare parameters for initialization of name, status, color;
    
    def __init__(self, parent, init_name, init_status, init_color):
        # implement tkinter Button through instance variable "master"
        self.master = tkinter.Button(parent, text=init_name, bg=init_color, command=self.button_click())
        # self.bg_color = init_color -- seems redundant, discontinued;
        self.is_active = init_status

    # create function that serves as command for button
    def button_click(self):
        if not self.is_active:
            self.is_active = True
        else:
            self.is_active = False


test_Window = tkinter.Tk()
test_Button = ChoiceButton(test_Window, "Test", False, "Blue")
test_Button.master.pack()

test_Window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I just ran the posted code, I did not get any error. From the traceback, it's clear that the error was triggered from this `test_frame = Frame(main_Menu, row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")` line which isn't there in the posted code. What is `main_Menu` and why do you have gridding parameters in the `Frame` is it a class defined by you?

Comment: It appears you're trying to use an instance of `GameWindow` as the master/parent of another widget. You can't do that, because `GameWindow` isn't a widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley `GameWindow` is a composition I created based on `tkinter.Tk()`. So yes, it is not a widget. But neither is the original class, yet it works with Tk() instances. What are you suggesting exactly?

Comment: @AST main_Menu is an instance of `GameWindow`. Sorry for the confusion I have caused, I did not think this through enough. I will upload the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred to the GameWindow  instance directly instead to its master when I gave the button a parent parameter.

Sorry for taking your time with this, I was completely mislead by wrong conclusions.